# How to select nicedit instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicedit

I am creating and adding nicedit instance dynamically. I want to select the newly added instance. But I am not able to select the instance using Javascript. Please help me to resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for something like this

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<input id="add" type="button" value="Add text field"/>
<textarea id="dummy" name="dummy" cols="40" class="dummy"></textarea>
```

js:

```
var idnr = 0;
var NicEditor = new nicEditor();

$('#add').click(function(){
  var $clone = $('#dummy').clone();
  var id = 't_' + idnr;
  idnr = idnr + 1;
  $clone.attr('id',id).attr('name',id).removeClass('dummy');
  $('#wrapper').append($clone);
  NicEditor.panelInstance(id);
  console.log($('#wrapper').find('textarea'));
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8UZnV/show/
remove show to see the code

With the 'id' you can select the nicEditor instance

Comment: Thanks for you help. But I am not able to find any method to select nicEditor instance with id.

Comment: You can search for the instance with nicEditors.findEditor(id); Take a look here http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/521/Javascript%20API

Comment: nicEditors.findEditor(id) this give me the instance.In your example "http://jsfiddle.net/8UZnV/show/" create a text editor when user click "Add text here" button. and  user need to click on the text area to start typing text. But my requirements  is that once user click on "Add text here" and just start typing in the newly created text editor. no need to click again on the text area.

Comment: Yes you have instance and did you a look in it ? There is a varialbe elm, an anchor to the nicEdit-main div$(nicEditors.findEditor(id).elm).focus();

Comment: @nevtag how do I remove all instance once?